# Current source and resistor

Tags: current, current-source

If i have a current source and a resistor in parallel, i will have two nodes,if i ground the the node which faces in the direction of current of the current source will all the current flow to the ground? or will any current flow into the resistor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqGtut.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no return path from ground back to the other side of the source, therefore no current will flow to ground. *All* of the current will flow through the resistor.

Comment: what will happen when we apply source transformation to this circuit?

Comment: The current source will become a voltage source.